# Extended (step by step) explanation in answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For few of the questions, the only answer that suffices is a complete step by step explanation of all the steps (with screenshots). I know most folks, try their best to summarize their answers to a few highlights and that too extends to very large answers but still enough. So what they resort to is a link to some obsure blog entry (which over time turns into a dead link)

I have personally resorted in these cases to create a personal blog entry (wordpress) and provide a link as additional information on the actual answer. But in that case, does not the actual purpose of SE (to aggregate solutions into one place where they will not get lost in time) drop short.

So my question is is there a way we can save lengthy / step by step answers somewhere in StackExchange? Maybe like a blog entry (Is this just a new feature suggestion, IDK?)

As always, glad to be part of this great community!

Answer (score 3):

I'd say summarize those steps. I think what we don't like seeing are just plain link answers that can eventually become dead links, and have before many times. If you summarize the steps involved, that should suffice. If the "answer" is something a little more in depth for a question that involves a lot of explanation (like the homework questions), you could use an answer to get them started on their research. Sometimes "I need a rotating webpart" shouldn't require the entire answer to be the full solution waiting for them to copy/paste--but that's my opinion.

Comment: At times you need to link an external source because the code to copy is too long or it is not formatted properly in the source so copy pasting again would result in a distortion of the code. Or the answer is a clue to a similar solution or a clue on where to start to create your own solution, so if you replicate that too literally the person will easily vote you down because it is not EXACTLY the answer to the question.

Comment: +1 Mike! Followed your example for this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194616/sharepoint-search-application-in-sharepoint-2013-foundation/194617#194617